# Get Meta Keyword By ID in Magento

Tags: magento, keyword, meta

I want to display Meta Keyword of a Product in view.phtml file.
What function do i need to call upon to display meta keyword of that particular product in Magento.

Comment: do you want to display it for viewers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the meta keyword of the rendered product, use following within your view.phtml:

```
<?php echo $_product->getMetaKeyword(); ?>
```

You can get meta keyword by product id with:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getMetaKeyword(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes i got it worked, by using $this->getProduct()->getMetaKeyword();